# Can't change laptop display brightness

Tags: c++, winapi, display, brightness, hdmi

I'm working on C++ display brightness regulation program for windows 10.
The setup is: notebook with internal display + external HDMI display.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")

void ListMonitorsAndAdapters()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice;
    displayDevice.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

    for (DWORD deviceIndex = 0; EnumDisplayDevices(nullptr, deviceIndex, &displayDevice, 0); deviceIndex++)
    {
        std::wcout << "Monitor: " << displayDevice.DeviceName << " Video Adapter: " << displayDevice.DeviceString << std::endl;
    }
}

void SetMonitorBrightness_f(HANDLE hMonitor, DWORD newBrightness)
{
    DWORD minBrightness, maxBrightness, currentBrightness;
    if (GetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, &minBrightness, &currentBrightness, &maxBrightness))
    {
        DWORD newNormalizedBrightness = (newBrightness * (maxBrightness - minBrightness)) / 100 + minBrightness;
        SetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, newNormalizedBrightness);
    }
}

std::vector<HANDLE> GetPhysicalMonitors()
{
    std::vector<HANDLE> physicalMonitors;

    std::vector<HMONITOR> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, [](HMONITOR monitor, HDC, LPRECT, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL {
        std::vector<HMONITOR>* monitors = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HMONITOR>*>(lParam);
    monitors->push_back(monitor);
    return TRUE;
        }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors));

    for (HMONITOR monitor : monitors)
    {
        DWORD numPhysicalMonitors;
        if (GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, &numPhysicalMonitors))
        {
            if (numPhysicalMonitors == 1)
            {
                // Laptop monitor
                PHYSICAL_MONITOR physicalMonitor;
                if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, 1, &physicalMonitor))
                {
                    physicalMonitors.push_back(physicalMonitor.hPhysicalMonitor);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Secondary monitor (HDMI monitor, etc.)
                PHYSICAL_MONITOR* physicalMonitorArray = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[numPhysicalMonitors];
                if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(monitor, numPhysicalMonitors, physicalMonitorArray))
                {
                    for (DWORD i = 0; i < numPhysicalMonitors; ++i)
                    {
                        physicalMonitors.push_back(physicalMonitorArray[i].hPhysicalMonitor);
                    }
                }
                delete[] physicalMonitorArray;
            }
        }
    }

    return physicalMonitors;
}

int main()
{
    ListMonitorsAndAdapters();
    std::vector<HANDLE> physicalMonitors = GetPhysicalMonitors();
    if (physicalMonitors.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Both laptop monitor and HDMI monitor are not detected." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Adjust brightness of the laptop monitor (primary monitor)
    DWORD laptopBrightness = 20;  // Adjust the value as desired (0-100)
    SetMonitorBrightness_f(physicalMonitors[0], laptopBrightness);

    // Adjust brightness of the HDMI monitor (secondary monitor)
    if (physicalMonitors.size() > 1)
    {
        DWORD hdmiBrightness = 50;  // Adjust the value as desired (0-100)
        SetMonitorBrightness_f(physicalMonitors[1], hdmiBrightness);
    }
}
```

The problem is that brightness is changing only for HDMI display but not for internal notebook display.

```
ListMonitorsAndAdapters() function cout:
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY1 Video Adapter: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY2 Video Adapter: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY3 Video Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY4 Video Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY5 Video Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY6 Video Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
```

I tried different methods to open internal notebook display like

```
HANDLE hMonitor = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\LCD", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr);
```

but still no luck.

Comment: Is the call `GetMonitorBrightness` failing? If it is failing, what does `GetLastError` return?  Is max and min the same value? Does `GetMonitorCapabilities` indicate the monitor even supports the function (as per `MC_CAPS_BRIGHTNESS`)?

Comment: This is a notorious issue with laptops.  They control brightness with the BIOS, driven by the Fn-key feature.

Comment: @Eljay
[if (GetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, &minBrightness, &currentBrightness, &maxBrightness)) {
        DWORD newNormalizedBrightness = (newBrightness * (maxBrightness - minBrightness)) / 100 + minBrightness;
        SetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, newNormalizedBrightness);
    }
    else         
        std::cerr << "Failed to get display brightness. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;]
Failed to get display brightness. Error code: 3223725449

Comment: HRESULT Decoder [3223725449](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3223725449) says "**ERROR_GRAPHICS_DDCCI_INVALID_MESSAGE_COMMAND**: An operation failed because a DDC/CI message had an invalid value in its command field."  That's probably the reason then.

Comment: @Eljay
Error in GetMonitorCapabilities. Error code: 3223725449
So the error code is the same like for SetMonitorBrightness(). Maybe I put wrong monitor device to hMonitor for laptop display?

Comment: I'm not sure, I only know about those particular APIs from what I just read today on MSDN.  I have a lot of experience with input devices like pens, dials, mice, keyboards, tablets / touch, using either WinTab or Win Ink APIs.  Reading the MSDN document, checking the return codes, and last error, and stepping through the code with a debugger are my "go to" tools for figuring out these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Eljay, will try change brightness using WMI

Comment: Thanks for your interest guys! I found a solution. Described it in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to change laptop display brightness by using WMI from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707114/how-to-pass-wmic-parameters-for-wmisetbrightness). It's a bit dirty method but it works (should be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333195/change-brightness-using-wmi), but I never had to make it work). So the final **code for changing both HDMI and notebook displays brightness**:

```
#include <Windows.h>                              // Windows API
#include <ShellAPI.h>                             // ShellExecute
#include <string>                                 // std::wstring
#include <iostream>                               // std::cout, std::cerr
#include <highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>     // Display brightness functions
#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")                 // Link Dxva2.lib library

HANDLE hMonitor{ nullptr };                       // Handle to the monitor

// Function to retrieve the handle of the monitor
HANDLE GetMonitor() {
    DWORD NumberOfPhysicalMonitors{ 0 };
    PHYSICAL_MONITOR* PhysicalMonitors{ nullptr };

    // Get the handle of the monitor from the top-level window
    HMONITOR hMonitor{ MonitorFromWindow(GetTopWindow(nullptr), NULL) };

    // Return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if the monitor handle is invalid
    if (!hMonitor || hMonitor == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    // Get the number of physical monitors and allocate memory for the physical monitors
    if (!GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &NumberOfPhysicalMonitors)) {
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    PhysicalMonitors = static_cast<PHYSICAL_MONITOR*>(malloc(
        NumberOfPhysicalMonitors * sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR)
    ));

    // Get the physical monitors from the monitor handle
    if (!GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor,
        NumberOfPhysicalMonitors,
        PhysicalMonitors)) {
        free(PhysicalMonitors);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    // Return the handle of the physical monitor
    return PhysicalMonitors->hPhysicalMonitor;
}

int main()
{
    int HDMI_DisplayBrightnessLevel   = 50; // The desired HDMI display brightness level
    int Laptop_DisplayBrightnessLevel = 70; // The desired laptop display brightness level

    // Get the current brightness of the monitor
    DWORD Min, Current, Max;
    if (!GetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor = GetMonitor(), &Min, &Current, &Max)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get display brightness. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the brightness of the HDMI display
    if (!SetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, HDMI_DisplayBrightnessLevel)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set HDMI display brightness. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the brightness of the laptop display using PowerShell command
    std::wstring command = L"powershell.exe -Command \"(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(0," + std::to_wstring(Laptop_DisplayBrightnessLevel) + L")\"";
    int result = (int)ShellExecute(nullptr, L"open", L"powershell.exe", command.c_str(), nullptr, SW_HIDE);
    if (result <= 32)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to execute PowerShell command. Error code: " << result << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPD. Finlay got it works with WMI Class. So now you have 2 functions to control notebook display brightness (WMI or PowerShell) and 1 for HDMI display**:

```
#include <objbase.h>                            // provides COM (Component Object Model) initialization and uninitialization functions. COM is a binary interface standard for software components to interact with each other.
#include <stdio.h>                              // provides standard I/O functions like printf and scanf for input and output operations.
#include <comdef.h>                             // provides COM utility functions, including helper classes and macros for COM programming.
#include <wbemidl.h>                            // provides WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) COM interfaces. WMI is a Microsoft technology for managing and accessing system information in a Windows environment.
#include <windows.h>                            // provides the Windows API, which includes functions, constants, and data types for interacting with the Windows operating system.
#include <ShellAPI.h>                           // provides the ShellExecute function, which allows you to execute a file or open it with its associated application.
#include <string>                               // provides the std::wstring class, which represents a wide string of characters. Wide strings are used to store Unicode text.
#include <iostream>                             // provides the std::cout and std::cerr objects for console output. std::cout is used for standard output, while std::cerr is used for error output.
#include <highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>   // provides functions for controlling display brightness at a high level. It allows you to adjust the brightness of monitors connected to the system.
#include <chrono>                               // provides facilities for measuring and manipulating time. It includes the std::chrono namespace, which contains classes and functions for time-related operations.
#include <thread>                               // provides facilities for creating and managing threads. It includes the std::thread class, which represents a single thread of execution.
#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")               // pragma directive instructs the linker to link the Dxva2.lib library. The library contains functions and resources related to DirectX Video Acceleration (DXVA), which is a Microsoft API for hardware-accelerated video decoding.
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")            // pragma directive instructs the linker to link the wbemuuid.lib library. The library contains the UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) definitions required for using WMI COM interfaces.

using namespace std; // directive that allows you to use names from the std namespace without explicitly qualifying them with the namespace prefix.

HANDLE hMonitor{ nullptr };  // Handle to the monitor

// Function to retrieve the handle of the monitor
HANDLE GetMonitor() {
    DWORD NumberOfPhysicalMonitors{ 0 };
    PHYSICAL_MONITOR* PhysicalMonitors{ nullptr };

    // Get the handle of the monitor from the top-level window
    HMONITOR hMonitor{ MonitorFromWindow(GetTopWindow(nullptr), NULL) };

    // Return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if the monitor handle is invalid
    if (!hMonitor || hMonitor == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    // Get the number of physical monitors and allocate memory for the physical monitors
    if (!GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &NumberOfPhysicalMonitors)) {
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    PhysicalMonitors = static_cast<PHYSICAL_MONITOR*>(malloc(
        NumberOfPhysicalMonitors * sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR)
    ));

    // Get the physical monitors from the monitor handle
    if (!GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor,
        NumberOfPhysicalMonitors,
        PhysicalMonitors)) {
        free(PhysicalMonitors);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    // Return the handle of the physical monitor
    return PhysicalMonitors->hPhysicalMonitor;
}

// Function to set HDMI display brightness using WinAPI
int setHDMIDisplayBrightness_WinAPI(uint8_t brightness) {
    
    if (brightness > 100) brightness = 100; // check if brightness value is out of range
        
    // Get the current brightness of the of the HDMI display
    DWORD Min, Current, Max;
    if (!GetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor = GetMonitor(), &Min, &Current, &Max)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get display brightness. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the brightness of the HDMI display
    if (!SetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, brightness)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set HDMI display brightness. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

// Function to set notebook display brightness using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)
int setNotebookDisplayBrightness_WMI(uint8_t brightness) {

    if (brightness > 100) brightness = 100; // check if brightness value is out of range

    IWbemLocator* pLocator = NULL;   // Pointer to the IWbemLocator interface
    IWbemServices* pNamespace = 0;   // Pointer to the IWbemServices interface
    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL; // Pointer to the IWbemClassObject interface
    IWbemClassObject* pInClass = NULL;   // Pointer to the IWbemClassObject interface for input arguments
    IWbemClassObject* pInInst = NULL;    // Pointer to the IWbemClassObject interface for input instance
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnum = NULL;  // Pointer to the IEnumWbemClassObject interface for enumerating objects
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;  // HRESULT variable for storing function return values

    BSTR path = SysAllocString(L"root\\wmi");   // Allocate a BSTR and initialize it with the specified string
    BSTR ClassPath = SysAllocString(L"WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods");   // Allocate a BSTR and initialize it with the specified string
    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"WmiSetBrightness");   // Allocate a BSTR and initialize it with the specified string
    BSTR ArgName0 = SysAllocString(L"Timeout");   // Allocate a BSTR and initialize it with the specified string
    BSTR ArgName1 = SysAllocString(L"Brightness");   // Allocate a BSTR and initialize it with the specified string
    BSTR bstrQuery = SysAllocString(L"Select * from WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods");   // Allocate a BSTR and initialize it with the specified string


    // Checks if any of the variables path, ClassPath, MethodName, or ArgName0 is null
    if (!path || !ClassPath || !MethodName || !ArgName0)
    {
        printf("SysAllocString failed. Out of memory.\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize Component Object Model (COM)
    hr = CoInitialize(0);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("CoInitialize returned 0x%x:", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize COM security settings
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        EOAC_SECURE_REFS, //change to EOAC_NONE if you change dwAuthnLevel to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE
        NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("CoInitializeSecurity returned 0x%x:", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Create an instance of the WbemLocator object
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLocator);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("CoCreateInstance returned 0x%x:", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Connect to the WMI server
    hr = pLocator->ConnectServer(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &pNamespace);
    printf("\n\nConnectServer returned 0x%x:", hr);
    if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
        goto cleanup;

    // Set the security blanket on the proxy
    hr = CoSetProxyBlanket(pNamespace,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        EOAC_NONE
    );

    if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
        goto cleanup;

    // Execute a query on the namespace
    hr = pNamespace->ExecQuery(_bstr_t(L"WQL"), //Query Language
        bstrQuery, //Query to Execute
        WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, //Make a semi-synchronous call
        NULL, //Context
        &pEnum //Enumeration Interface
    );

    if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
        goto cleanup;

    hr = WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;

    // Iterate through the objects returned by the query
    while (WBEM_S_NO_ERROR == hr)
    {
        // Get the next object from the collection
        ULONG ulReturned;
        IWbemClassObject* pObj;
        DWORD retVal = 0;

        hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, //Timeout
            1, //No of objects requested
            &pObj, //Returned Object
            &ulReturned //No of object returned
        );

        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        // Get the class object
        hr = pNamespace->GetObject(ClassPath, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
        printf("\nGetObject returned 0x%x:", hr);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        // Get the input argument and set the property
        hr = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pInClass, NULL);
        printf("\nGetMethod returned 0x%x:", hr);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        // Create an instance of the input argument class
        hr = pInClass->SpawnInstance(0, &pInInst);
        printf("\nSpawnInstance returned 0x%x:", hr);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        // Set the value of the first argument (timeout)
        VARIANT var1;
        VariantInit(&var1);
        V_VT(&var1) = VT_BSTR;
        V_BSTR(&var1) = SysAllocString(L"0");
        hr = pInInst->Put(ArgName0, 0, &var1, CIM_UINT32); //CIM_UINT64
        printf("\nPut ArgName0 returned 0x%x:", hr);
        VariantClear(&var1);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        // Set the value of the second argument (brightness)
        VARIANT var;
        VariantInit(&var);
        var.vt = VT_UI1;
        var.uiVal = brightness;
        hr = pInInst->Put(ArgName1, 0, &var, 0);
        VariantClear(&var);
        printf("\nPut ArgName1 returned 0x%x:", hr);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        // Call the method
        VARIANT pathVariable;
        VariantInit(&pathVariable);
        hr = pObj->Get(_bstr_t(L"__PATH"), 0, &pathVariable, NULL, NULL);
        printf("\npObj Get returned 0x%x:", hr);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;

        hr = pNamespace->ExecMethod(pathVariable.bstrVal, MethodName, 0, NULL, pInInst, NULL, NULL);
        VariantClear(&pathVariable);
        printf("\nExecMethod returned 0x%x:", hr);
        if (hr != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
            goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Terminating normally\n");


    // Free up resources
cleanup:
    SysFreeString(path);   // Free the BSTR
    SysFreeString(ClassPath);   // Free the BSTR
    SysFreeString(MethodName);   // Free the BSTR
    SysFreeString(ArgName0);   // Free the BSTR
    SysFreeString(ArgName1);   // Free the BSTR
    SysFreeString(bstrQuery);   // Free the BSTR

    if (pClass)
        pClass->Release();   // Release the IWbemClassObject interface
    if (pInInst)
        pInInst->Release();   // Release the IWbemClassObject interface
    if (pInClass)
        pInClass->Release();   // Release the IWbemClassObject interface
    if (pLocator)
        pLocator->Release();   // Release the IWbemLocator interface
    if (pNamespace)
        pNamespace->Release();   // Release the IWbemServices interface
    CoUninitialize();   // Uninitialize the COM library
    return 0;   // Return 0 to indicate successful execution
}

// Function to set notebook display brightness using Windows PowerShell
int setNotebookDisplayBrightness_PShell(uint8_t brightness) {

    if (brightness > 100) brightness = 100; // check if brightness value is out of range

    // Set the brightness of the laptop display using PowerShell command
    std::wstring command = L"powershell.exe -Command \"(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(0," + std::to_wstring(brightness) + L")\"";
    int result = (int)ShellExecute(nullptr, L"open", L"powershell.exe", command.c_str(), nullptr, SW_HIDE);
    if (result <= 32)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to execute PowerShell command. Error code: " << result << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(int iArgCnt, char** argv)
{
    int HDMI_DisplayBrightnessLevel = 40;   // The desired HDMI display brightness level
    int Laptop_DisplayBrightnessLevel = 70; // The desired laptop display brightness level

    // Check if the required command-line arguments are provided
    if (iArgCnt != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Insufficient command-line arguments. Usage: Brightness_control.exe HDMI_Brightness_Level% Laptop_Brightness_Level%" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "For example: Brightness_control.exe 20 30" << std::endl;
        //return 1;
    }
    else{
        // Parse the command-line arguments and set the display brightness levels
        HDMI_DisplayBrightnessLevel = std::stoi(argv[1]);
        Laptop_DisplayBrightnessLevel = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    }

    setHDMIDisplayBrightness_WinAPI(HDMI_DisplayBrightnessLevel); // use WinAPI to set HDMI display brightness level

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000)); // Thread delayed for 1 seconds

    setNotebookDisplayBrightness_WMI(Laptop_DisplayBrightnessLevel);       // use WMI Class to change Notebook Display Brightness level
    // OR
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000)); // Thread delayed for 1 seconds
    setNotebookDisplayBrightness_PShell(Laptop_DisplayBrightnessLevel-50); // use Power Shell command to change Notebook Display Brightness level
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can access the [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-reference) from C++ directly. There's no reason to launch a process, and wait an eternity for PowerShell to initialize.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for comment. That's inspires me to try one more time and now it works with WMI Class. Updates in answer.